# findContour hierarchy in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv

I am trying to make sense of the hierarchy in the `findContour` function in OpenCV. I am using `RETR_CCOMP` to hopefully find the parent contours and whether or not they have 'children'. My find contour hierarchy vector seems to suggest there are far more parent contours then are visible in the output which makes it more difficult to use.

Is it possible to get around this problem?.

Here's my code:

```
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

Mat src;
Mat src_gray;
Mat src_edges;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    src = imread("image.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED);

    cvtColor(src, src_gray, CV_BGR2GRAY);
    blur(src_gray, src_gray, Size(3, 3));
    Canny(src_gray, src_edges, 200, 120);

    vector<vector<Point> > contours;
    vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;
    findContours(src_edges, contours, hierarchy, RETR_CCOMP, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_TC89_L1, Point(0, 0));


    for (auto vec : hierarchy)
        std::cout << vec << std::endl; // just to have a look at the hierarchy vector

    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){


        if (hierarchy[i][3] != 0){
            count++;
        }
    }

    cout << "number of labels = " << count << endl;


    Mat drawing = Mat::zeros(src_gray.size(), CV_8UC3);
    for (int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++)
    {
        Scalar color = Scalar(rand() & 255, rand() & 255, rand() & 255);;
        drawContours(drawing, contours, i, color, 2, 8, hierarchy, 0, Point());

    }

    namedWindow("Contours", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    imshow("Contours", drawing);
    namedWindow("Original Image", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    imshow("Original Image", src);

    waitKey(0);
    return(0);
}
```

Here an example image:

[image]

Comment: can you provide the image you used for this?

Comment: `if(hierarchy[i][3] != -1)` should make more sense

Comment: I added a picture to the question. Ill try that now.

Comment: Thanks seems to be working for some of my pictures now. I just need to adjust the canny max and min for the others!